# Unchecked warning when creating instance of Vector

Tags: java

```
new Vector(1).addElement(new D (message))
```

I have the above statement as a method parameter. But it does not give me a new vector of size one with an element. Instead it yields void and Java complains about:

> Type safety: The method `addElement(Object)` belongs to the raw type
>   `Vector`. References to generic type `Vector<E>` should be parameterized

Why does it tell me to parameterize Vector and gives me the same error, when writing:

```
path.setElementAt (new Node (root, tag, new Vector<D>(1).addElement(new D (message)), next), path.size()-1);//TODO: how?
```

gives void for the parameterized vector as parameter:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The constructor Node(D, D, void, int) is undefined

Thanks a lot

Gerrit

Comment: Error is not related to the second line. Show us full code. And the difference between 2nd and 1st line is the solution.

Comment: The second line of code will not give you the warning.

Comment: What don't you understand about the warning on the first line of code?

Comment: 'path.setElementAt (new Node (root, tag, new Vector<D>(1).addElement(new D (message)), next), path.size()-1);//TODO: how?'

Comment: Don't post code in comments.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Vector.addElement(). What does it return? So why are you surprised that new Vector().addElement() is void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in 3 lines:

    `Vector vector = new Vector(1);

    vector.addElement(new D (message));

    path.setElementAt (new Node (root, tag, vector, next), path.size()-1);`

second line return void instead of vector, that is why you cannot use it as parameter in the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, the vector is not void anymore, now!